# SEAL - binary encoded ciphertext

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

In SEAL, am I able to convert a ciphertext that is encoded with polynomial to a ciphertext that is encoded as binary?

Comment: I do not actually think so. I could not find this info in the documentation though.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2017/11/sealmanual-2-3-1.pdf

Comment: Quick questions after reading it, You mean binary polynomial? Why do you need to this conversion? After all the computation you need to decrypt and get the plaintext.